# Radio button only returns "on" when submitted

Tags: php, forms, radio-button

I am very new to PHP and I am trying to display the value of a selected radio button in a string. But all I get returned is "on" instead of the value associated with the selection. Any help would be great!

```
<form action="Handle_form_PHP.php" method="post">
    <div class= "row">
      <div class ="col-25">
        <label for="student">Student</label>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-75">
        <input type="radio" name="student" value ="student">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class= "row">
      <div class ="col-25">
        <label for="student">Employee</label>
      </div>
      <div class ="col-75">
        <input type="radio" name="student" value = "employee">
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the PHP I am using to print:

```
// Create a shorthand for the form data:
$fname = $_REQUEST['firstname'];
$lname = $_REQUEST['lastname'];
$address = $_REQUEST['address'];
$state1 = $_REQUEST['state1'];
$state2 = $_REQUEST['state2'];
$student = $_POST['student'];

// Print the submitted information:
echo "<p>Thank you, <b> $student </b>, <b>$fname $lname</b>, for the filling out our survey:<br>
    <p>We will Send you your report at:  <i>$address</i>, <i>$state1</i><i>$state2</i>.</p>\n";
```

Comment: is your form method using GET or POST, and why are you using $_POST only for 'student'?

Comment: It is POST, I honestly was just using what the professor gave us and her code used $_REQUEST in all of them. I was searching what might be my problem with the Radio buttons and read to use POST. But it did not help

Comment: I just figured it out -.- after 30 minutes of searching. I put post instead of POST............. *sigh* Sorry!

Answer (score 1):

If your `$_POST['student']` superglobal variable was holding a value of 'on', then the issue has nothing to do with method case-sensitivity.

The default value for a radio button is 'on' unless you provide a `value` attribute inside the radio button tag.

Let me prove it to you.  Go to [cringe] https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_form_checkbox then paste the following snippet in the left-side box, then Run, then Submit.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form action="/action_page.php" method="get">
  <input type="radio" name="student" checked> Student<br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is submitting with a method of `get` (notice the lowercase `get` is inconsequential. `post` will behave the same way).  See that without a `value` in the student radio input, the submitted value is `on`.

If you write `value="Red42"` inside the radio input, you will no longer receive `on`; the submitted value is `Red42`.

Answer (score -2):

use POST not post when saying method:

```
<form action="Handle_form_PHP.php" method="POST">
```

not

```
<form action="Handle_form_PHP.php" method="post">
```

For the record, the book was incorrect and had "post"

Comment: Method value case-sensitivity is irrelevant.  Something else was wrong that you didn't notice.